# Google maps places: Adding placeDetails to click method of selected place

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

I got to work in sync my custom markers and markers from google places query. But i am having a hard time to figure out how to get details of a marker upon click with number,photo etc.

Basically i want to access all or a big amount of details from getDetails() method to access them when a click is triggered upon the marker and show them in the box of a marker for further use

```
//map options
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.055625, 14.504408),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

//adding collection of stored markers
function addMyMarkers() {
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    placeMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]), locations[i][0]);
  }
}
//query for getting place markers
function addFromSearch(request) {
    service.nearbySearch(request, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                $('#json').append($.toJSON(results[i]) + '<br><br>');
                //$("#debug").append("<img src='" + results[i].icon + "' />")
                //results[i].reference
                placeMarker(results[i].geometry.location, results[i].name,results[i].icon,results[i].photos);
                //google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', getDetails(results[i], i));
            }
        }
    });
}

//function for placing icon with content, custom icon, etc...
function placeMarker(location, content,icon) {
var image;
if (icon) {
    image = {
        url: icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
    };
}
//marker properties
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    icon: image
});


//click listener
//service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(content);
     // infowindow.setContent(details.name + "<br />" + details.formatted_address +"<br />" + details.website + "<br />" + details.rating + "<br />" + details.formatted_phone_number);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});


}
```

I hope i made a good first post on stackoverflow,  I tried to search as thorougly as i can to find the answer but didn't succeed. 
From Google API ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details

Comment: [This example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveD.html) retrieves the details on a click and displays them in the infoWindow.

Comment: Thank you, your example helped me, it is correct :)